# Finding recursive definition of $L := \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid (a-b) \text{ is a multiple of } 3\} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to come up with a recursive definition for the set:
$L := \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid (a-b) \text{ is a multiple of } 3\} $

Then I must also prove that (L' = L), where L' is set defined by the recursive definition using induction.

I am having problems understanding the set, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $T_0=L$ and $T_{i+1}=T_i\cup L$.

Comment: What part(s) of the problem are you struggling with?

Comment: Can you explain what elements $\mathbb{Z}^2$? I don't understand what elements the set encompasses.